# Find an array inside a matrix with tolerance

Tags: python

## Summary

Using `numpy`, I'm trying to find the value of a pixel (expressed as `[r,g,b]`) in a matrix which size is N by 3; so I want to find the row where the array is *but I want to add a tolerance because it can happen that it does not match exactly*.

With `np.all` (see raw below) it is possible to do this *but the value should be exactly the same*.

```py
result_primo_check = np.all(element_2_find==matrix, axis=1)
```

## Example

The problem is that I have `element_2_find = [144, 0, 256]` but in matrix the most similar row is `[148, 0, 250]`. Is there a command that add a tolerance or something similar?

Comment: This is actually a far more complicated question than you might think.  There is no flag or parameter to add a tolerance.  However, there are ways to solve it.  You can, for instance, create a function that is passed the two tuples (the two RGBs) and a threshold, and returns `True` if tuple1 - tuple2 is less than the threshold across all 3 dimensions.  Then you can do something like `np.all(my_nearly_equal_func(element_2_find, matrix, tol=5), axis=1)`.  HTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute whatever distance (e.g. Euclidean) you want to use between your pixel and the rest of the image and select the image location that matches most closely (perhaps only if the distance is below some threshold).

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(100, 3)
pixel = np.random.rand(1, 3)

dists = ((img - pixel) ** 2).sum(-1)
min_idx = np.unravel_index(dists.argmin(), dists.shape)
min_dist = dists[min_idx]
# img[min_idx] is the closest pixel in the image to your target pixel
print(min_idx, min_dist, img[min_idx])
```